# How to use the current select column value in a column sub select in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that for each row, adds a comma seperated string to one column using a sub query. So for example, a work order may be attached to many parts. I do my regular select, but use the SQL function 'STUFF' to build the 'Parts column. That way in the results, the arts column has multiple entries. So i do i do the sub query for the column i use 'STUFF" on to get all parts using the main column id of the base query? This is a little weird for me to explain but this snippet will help you understand what i am trying to accomplish:

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET FMTONLY OFF;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_KikusuiRpt') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP_KikusuiRpt

-- Get the current date to work on if they do not send in date params. Meaning it is automated run --
-- if hey do send in date ranges, then it is manual run 


IF NULLIF(@StartDate, '') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Set start date param to the first day of the current month
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()), 0)   
    END
IF NULLIF(@EndDate, '') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Set end day to the last day what ever that may be of the current month.
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
    END

SELECT  
    manufacturer.mfrname AS Manufacturer, 
    model.modelnumber AS BaseModelNumber,
    control.controlserialnumber AS Serial, 
    Customer.CustCompany,
    Control.ControlDateAdded as Received,
    Control.ControlCalDate as 'Completed (Cal Date)',
    WorkOrder.WorkOrderID as woid,
    Receiver.ReceiverID,
    WorkOrderComments.CommentRcvr as 'Receiver Comments',
    WorkOrderCOmments.CommentRpt as 'Report Comments',
    ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PartID
        FROM WorkOrderPart WOP
            INNER JOIN WorkORder WO ON WOP.WorkOrderID = WO.WorkOrderID                         
            INNER JOIN Model ON Model.ModelID = WO.ModelID
         WHERE WO.MfrCode IN (SELECT MfrCode FROM Manufacturer where MfrName LIKE '%Kikusui%')
            --
            -- Right here i need somehow to do this
            --  
            --   the workorder on the stuff query needs to be attached to the base select work order row instance, or else i get all parts in each row not just for the work order
           where wo.WorkOrderID = WOID

        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''), 'NA') AS Parts

INTO #TEMP_KikusuiRpt
FROM WorkOrder 
INNER JOIN Control ON WorkOrder.ControlNumber = Control.ControlNumber
INNER JOIN model ON control.modelid = model.modelid 
INNER JOIN manufacturer on model.mfrcode = manufacturer.mfrcode         
INNER JOIN WorkOrderComments ON WorkOrderComments.WorkOrderID = WorkOrder.WorkOrderID   
INNER JOIN Receiver ON Receiver.ReceiverID = WorkOrder.ReceiverID
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustID = WorkOrder.CustID

WHERE Manufacturer.MfrName LIKE '%Kikusui%' 

AND @StartDate > WorkOrder.DateReceived 
AND @EndDate < WorkOrder.DateCompleted

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_KikusuiRpt

DROP TABLE #TEMP_KikusuiRpt
```

So hopefully i have explained this clearly enough. Is there a way to handle this? The reason being that my Parts column is populated, but not filtered enough to the model that is returned.

Comment: Is the only rout is to make a temp table with the main query, and the Parts column as empty varchar. Then create another UPDATE select into the temp table to fill the Parts column using the temp tables ModelNumber.

Comment: No, and for what the above query is doing, you don't even need to select into a temp table.

Comment: I select into a tmp because it is used in another section of the query later on. I just displayed this part for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to alias your outer and inner `model` table references. Here's what the main select would look like:

```
SELECT  
    manufacturer.mfrname AS Manufacturer, 
    m1.modelnumber AS BaseModelNumber,
    control.controlserialnumber AS Serial, 
    Customer.CustCompany,
    Control.ControlDateAdded as Received,
    Control.ControlCalDate as 'Completed (Cal Date)',
    WorkOrder.WorkOrderID as woid,
    Receiver.ReceiverID,
    WorkOrderComments.CommentRcvr as 'Receiver Comments',
    WorkOrderCOmments.CommentRpt as 'Report Comments',
    ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PartID
        FROM WorkOrderPart WOP
            INNER JOIN WorkORder WO ON WOP.WorkOrderID = WO.WorkOrderID                         
            INNER JOIN Model m2 ON m2.ModelID = WO.ModelID
         WHERE WO.MfrCode IN (SELECT MfrCode FROM Manufacturer where MfrName LIKE '%Kikusui%')
            AND m1.modelnumber = m2.modelnumber
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''), 'NA') AS Parts
INTO #TEMP_KikusuiRpt
FROM WorkOrder 
INNER JOIN Control ON WorkOrder.ControlNumber = Control.ControlNumber
INNER JOIN model  m1 ON control.modelid = m1.modelid 
INNER JOIN manufacturer on m1.mfrcode = manufacturer.mfrcode         
INNER JOIN WorkOrderComments ON WorkOrderComments.WorkOrderID = WorkOrder.WorkOrderID   
INNER JOIN Receiver ON Receiver.ReceiverID = WorkOrder.ReceiverID
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustID = WorkOrder.CustID
WHERE Manufacturer.MfrName LIKE '%Kikusui%' 
    AND @StartDate > WorkOrder.DateReceived 
    AND @EndDate < WorkOrder.DateCompleted
```

Comment: I calrified what fields to need. It would need to be able to reach base slect data within the STUFF query or else i get all parts instead of only parts for the current row.  So WHERE WO.WorkORderID = WOID (base alias)